# Restoring a managed SQL instance in Azure using PowerShell

Tags: restore, azure-sql-database, powershell, azure

I am trying to figure out how to restore a database from one managed SQL instance to another. I'm following the tutorials, but I keep running into inscrutable error messages.

Here's my command:

```
Restore-AzSqlInstanceDatabase `
    -Name "SomeDatabase" `
    -InstanceName "our-oltp-dev" `
    -ResourceGroupName "dev-managedsqlinstances" `
    -PointInTime "4/7/2020 12:00:00" `
    -TargetInstanceDatabaseName "SomeDatabase_FROM_DEV" `
    -TargetInstanceName "our-oltp-sandbox" `
    -TargetResourceGroupName "sandbox-managedsqlinstances"
```

Here's the output:

```
PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> Restore-AzSqlInstanceDatabase `
    -Name "SomeDatabase" `
    -InstanceName "our-oltp-dev" `
    -ResourceGroupName "dev-managedsqlinstances" `
    -PointInTime "4/7/2020 12:00:00" `
    -TargetInstanceDatabaseName "SomeDatabase_FROM_DEV" `
    -TargetInstanceName "our-oltp-sandbox" `
    -TargetResourceGroupName "sandbox-managedsqlinstances"
Restore-AzSqlInstanceDatabase : Parameter set cannot be resolved using the specified named parameters.
At line:1 char:1
+ Restore-AzSqlInstanceDatabase `
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Restore-AzSqlInstanceDatabase], ParameterBindingException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : AmbiguousParameterSet,Microsoft.Azure.Commands.Sql.ManagedDatabase.Cmdlet.RestoreAzureRmSqlManagedDatabase
```

It's a copy-and-paste from the Azure docs; so I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

This command is somehow not clear for PowerShell and there is problem to determine which version of the method is accurate.

However it should work if you specify `-FromPointInTimeBackup` switch, I have checked  it and got credentials error which is fine as I am not logged in to proper account.

```
PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> Restore-AzSqlInstanceDatabase `
>>     -Name "SomeDatabase" `
>>     -InstanceName "our-oltp-dev" `
>>     -ResourceGroupName "dev-managedsqlinstances" `
>>     -PointInTime "4/7/2020 12:00:00" `
>>     -TargetInstanceDatabaseName "SomeDatabase_FROM_DEV" `
>>     -TargetInstanceName "our-oltp-sandbox" `
>>     -TargetResourceGroupName "sandbox-managedsqlinstances" `
>>     -FromPointInTimeBackup
Restore-AzSqlInstanceDatabase : Your Azure credentials have not been set up or have expired, please run
Connect-AzAccount to set up your Azure credentials.
At line:1 char:1
+ Restore-AzSqlInstanceDatabase `
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : CloseError: (:) [Restore-AzSqlInstanceDatabase], ArgumentException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.Azure.Commands.Sql.ManagedDatabase.Cmdlet.RestoreAzureRmSqlManagedDatabase
```

Additionaly, be sure that you use the latest version of Az.Sql module.

```
Update-Module -Name Az.Sql -Force
```